# multiple columns from a single table to different variables tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, select

I am using Microsoft sql server database and I will develop a detailed stored procedure with T-SQL. My aim is to write the most ideal code in terms of time and performance and I need to get columns from the table with more than one select, this is my current code;

```
set @IA = (select A from clients with(nolock) WHERE STATUS=1 AND ID=@id)
set @IB = (select B from clients with(nolock) WHERE STATUS=1 AND ID=@id)
set @IC = (select B from clients with(nolock) WHERE STATUS=1 AND ID=@id)
```

How can I write a faster or more useful select query than this, with variable assignment?

Comment: Is there a unique index on `STATUS` guaranteeing only one row is returned?

Comment: The post WHERE field is more in the query I'm writing, I'm updating the question. I don't think it's important here.

Comment: Side note: you really shouldn't ue `NOLOCK`, it has serious data integrity implications.

Answer (score 1):

```
select @IA = A, @IB = B, @IC=B 
from clients
WHERE STATUS = 1;
```

Would be just fine.

Comment: This does have different semantics if multiple or no rows are returned. In the event of multiple rows matching `STATUS=1` their original query would return the `Subquery returned more than 1 value.` error this would just make an arbitrary assignment. In the event of no rows matching `STATUS=1` the original queries would set the variables to null. This version will leave the variables unassigned (often they will just be null anyway but this may not be the case if they were previously assigned a value)

Comment: @MartinSmith when would it assign multiple to a variable?

Comment: It won't assign multiple. It will silently assign an arbitrary one rather than raise an error

Comment: @MartinSmith, original one in code was a pseudo one, no? It would be an error otherwise. Anyway, if it was intended to return a single result, then it is fine anyway.